# How to prove some statements about divisibility and the $\gcd$ function

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, arithmetic

Struggling with some number theory homework. Could use a helping hand. The two statements are as follows

1. $\gcd(c, ab) \mid \gcd(c,a)\gcd(c,b)$
2. If $c \mid ab$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $c=\gcd(a,c)\gcd(b,c)$

I'm supposed to figure out a proof for each, but cannot even seem to get them started.

Comment: I edited to make your title a bit shorter (it doesn't need to contain the whole question) and to add some MathJax formatting. To see how to use MathJax for this kind of thing, you can click the "edited X min ago" link to see the code.

Comment: Do you know the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (unique factorization)?

Comment: It was glossed over shortly in class, maybe given 10 minutes, if that. After reading it in the book, I understand it but would probably fall short if I had to teach it to someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (FTA). These hints will guide you to a solution to 2.

1. Write out $a$ and $b$ with the FTA. Do they share any primes?
2. In general, what is $\gcd(x,y)$ in terms of the factorizations of $x$ and $y$?
3. Put these together to conclude the answer to 2.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, try Bezout's identity in questions about $\gcd$. In the first case, solve for integers $x,y,z,w$ the equations:

$$ax+cy = (a,c)\\bw+cz=(b,c)$$

Multiply these together and show that there is a solution to:

$$(ab)X+cY = (a,c)(b,c)$$

So $(ab,c)\mid (a,c)(b,c)$.

The other question requires a little more, but you can use the first part to get that $c\mid (a,c)(b,c)$ in the second part.

But we also know that $(a,c)\mid c$ and $(b,c)\mid c$. Use that $(a,c)$ and $(b,c)$ are relatively prime to show that $(a,c)(b,c)\mid c$.

Comment: Cant seem to get a solution to $(ab)X+cY=(a,c)(b,c)$.

Comment: Multiply the two equations to get: $$(a,c)(b,c)=(ax+cy)(bw+cz) = ab(xw) + c(ybw+axz+cyz)$$

Comment: Or you can use modular arithmetic: $(a,c)\equiv ax\pmod c$ and $(b,c)\equiv bw\pmod c$ so $(a,c)(b,c)\equiv ab(xw)\pmod c$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $v_p(x)$ denote the "valuation of $x$ at $p$" -- that is, the number of times the prime $p$ divides the integer $c$ (and $v_p(0) = +\infty$, if we allow zero in our discussion). e.g. $v_2(12) = 2$, because $2^2 | 12$ but $2^3 \!\!\not|\: 12$.

Then $\gcd(a,b) = c$ if and only if, for every prime $p$, $v_p(c) = \min\{v_p(a), v_p(b)\}$.

Similarly, $x | y$ if and only if, for every prime $p$, $v_p(x) \leq v_p(y)$.

Translating your questions into this form will make them rather simple!

Note that this amounts to a systematic way of working algebraically with the unique factorizations of integers.